# Counting the number of connected components in a complement

Tags: homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

I have come across the following problem. Suppose you are given a closed, connected, orientable n-dimensional submanifold without boundary, in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, call this submanifold $K$. Prove that $\mathbb{R}^{n+1} \setminus K$ has 2 connected components.

My initial idea was to start with a tubular neighborhood of $K$, call it $T$. This deformation retracts onto $K$, but is open. Now, apply the Meyer-Vietoris theorem to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus K$ and $T$. The intersection of these two sets is $T\setminus K$ which should have two components (looking at an example of $S^1$ in an open annulus in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for intuition).

This gives me the exact sequence $\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \oplus H_0({\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus K}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R} \rightarrow 0$.

Recalling that $H_0(M)$ consists of constant functions and the first map in the Meyer Vietoris sequence is $\omega \rightarrow (\omega|_T, \omega|_{{\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus K}})$ (that is it, is just a restriction of the 0-form to the components) the first map is in fact injective. Since the sequence is exact, the kernel of the second map is the image of the first, and the image of the second, the kernel of the third. Hence, the image of the second map is $\mathbb{R} \oplus \mathbb{R}$ and the kernel is $\mathbb{R}$ so the rank of $\mathbb{R} \oplus H_0({\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus K})$ is 3 so the rank of $H_0({\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\setminus K})$ is 2.

Is this the right way to approach this?

Comment: the easiest way, i think, is the Alexander duality.

Comment: This is a problem from a standard class in smooth manifolds where Alexander duality is not covered, so there should be a solution which does not require it.

Comment: Alexander duality says that $\widetilde{H}^0(S^{n+1}\setminus K)=H_n(K)=\mathbb Z$, so $H^0(S^{n+1}\setminus K)=H^0(\mathbb R^{n+1}\setminus K)=\mathbb Z^2$. your proof is correct, and i can write down one more (geometrical one), if you want. or how can i help?

Comment: I was just hoping someone could confirm my work. I'm a little new to this. :p